# Python :: Attribute in superclass not available in inheriting subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm wondering why the below fails; basically that an inheriting subclass (**SubClass**) doesn't appear to have access to an attribute in the superclass (**SuperClass**) that it inherits from.

By the way, all three files below are in the same directory and, for completeness, I'm using Python3.

Any ideas? I think it's something stunningly simple. Thank you!

The super class (**SuperClass** in **./super_class.py)** ...

```
class SuperClass(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.varSuper = 'varSuper_value'
```

The inheriting sub class (**SubClass** in **./sub_class.py)** ...

```
from super_class import SuperClass

class SubClass(SuperClass):

  def __init__(self):
     super(SuperClass, self).__init__()
     self.varSub = 'varSub_value'
```

The driver/tester script **(./driver.py)** ...

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from sub_class import SubClass

print(SubClass().varSub)    # Works: "varSub_value"
print(SubClass().varSuper)  # Excepts: I expected "varSuper_value"
```

The exception ...

```
user@linux$ ./driver.py
varSub_value                                  <--- GOOD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./driver.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(SubClass().varSuper)                <--- NO GOOD
AttributeError: 'SubClass' object has no attribute 'varSuper'
```

Comment: You should call `super()` without arguments in python 3

Comment: Or with the *correct* type - `super(` **`SubClass`** `, self)`

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for highlighting the distinction between Python2 and Python-3 usage of super().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) function wrong. You should be using:

```
super(SubClass, self).__init__()
```

Or in python3

```
super().__init__()
```

The way you have it written you are starting the MRO just after the parent class, not just after your own class..

Answer (score 0):

In the inheriting sub class (**SubClass** in **./sub_class.py)**, change this:

```
from super_class import SuperClass

class SubClass(SuperClass):

  def __init__(self):
     super(SuperClass, self).__init__()   # <---- INCORRECT. CHANGE THIS.
     self.varSub = 'varSub_value'
```

To this:

```
from super_class import SuperClass

class SubClass(SuperClass):

  def __init__(self):
     super(SubClass, self).__init__()   # <---- TO THIS in python-2 (also still valid in Python-3)
     super().__init__()                 # <---- OR THIS for python-3 (New style in python-3)
     self.varSub = 'varSub_value'
```

Btw, the python-3 new incantation avoids the possible bug of typing the wrong class.